# Hide doesn't work (intermittently) on Microsoft Office applications

Tags: macos, finder, ms-office

I find it SO annoying when Command + h doesn't hide an application.  Somehow Microsoft's developers seemed to find a way to break that functionality on most Office apps.  Anyone know why this is?  I've seen this behavior across many different versions, but currently I am on 10.9.3 on OS, and Office 2011.

To clarify, this is not every time, but about half the time that hide fails to hide an app.

Comment: The cmd-h works on my MBA 10.9.3, with MS office 2011 word app. So give us more information to help you.

Comment: Same here, cmd-H works with my office apps (just tested with Excel, Outlook and Word).  My Mac is 10.9.3 and the Office apps are 14.4.2

Comment: Third "same here." Do other windowing shortcuts work, such as "command +m?" Test this behavior in another user account as well. The guess account will suffice.

Comment: It is intermittent, it works for me right now, but didn't an hour ago.  I have seen this behavior since 10.6, maybe earlier.  I don't know what causes it, but it's practically an every day occurrence, just not consistent.  OS X and Office are the only constants I can think of,

Comment: It's happening right now, what would you like me to test?

Comment: When I hit command + h the Menu bar switches from Excel to the finder, but the Excel document is still on top of the finder.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Test the shortcuts in a separate user account. Yes.

Comment: This has happened on several different computers throughout the last 5 years, surely it cannot be corrupted user preferences.  I tried with another account and it worked OK the first time, I'll try a few times and see if I can get it to fail.  I have two computers, a MBA and a Mac Mini and this sometimes happens on both.